# can't change the data related to the ID in Reactjs when update form

Tags: reactjs

**I creating a BlogSite using Reactjs**

*I have trouble when I update a post. After I clicked the update icon, the form data fill according to the post id. but I can't input anything it's like as readonly*

1. Get data according to id

   ```
       <Button style={{ color: 'white' }} size='small' onClick={() =>updatePost(post._id)}>
         <MoreHorizIcon />
       </Button>
   ```
2. dispatch action

   ```
     const updatePost = (id) => {dispatch(getPost(id))}
   ```
3. action code

   ```
     try {
       dispatch({ type: POST_GET_REQUEST })
       const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/posts/get/${id}`)
       dispatch({
         type: POST_GET_SUCCESS,
         payload: data
       })
     } catch (error) {
       dispatch({
         type: POST_GET_FAIL,
         payload:
           error.response && error.response.data.message
             ? error.response.data.message
             : error.message,
       })
     }
   }
   ```
4. reducer code

   ```
       switch (action.type) {
           case POST_GET_REQUEST:
               return { loading: true, post: [] }
           case POST_GET_SUCCESS:
               return { loading: false, success: true, post: action.payload }
           case POST_GET_FAIL:
               return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
           default:
               return state
       }
   }
   ```
5. store code

   `const reducer = combineReducers({postGet: postGetReducer})`
6. FormScreen.js

   ```
   import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
   import { TextField, Typography, Paper } from '@mui/material'

   import { createPost } from '../actions/postsAction'

   const FormScreen = () => {
     const dispatch = useDispatch()

     const postGet = useSelector((state) => state.postGet)

     const [newUser, setNewAuthor] = useState({
       creator: '',
       title: '',
       message: '',
       tags: '',
       photo: '',
     })

     const handleChange = (e) => {
       setNewAuthor({ ...newUser, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

     }

     const handlePhoto = (e) => {
       setNewAuthor({ ...newUser, photo: e.target.files[0] })
     }

     const handleSubmit = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault()
       const formData = new FormData()
       formData.append('photo', newUser.photo)
       formData.append('creator', newUser.creator)
       formData.append('title', newUser.title)
       formData.append('message', newUser.message)
       formData.append('tags', newUser.tags)

       dispatch(createPost(formData))
     }

     return (
       <Paper>
         <form
           onSubmit={handleSubmit}
           encType='multipart/form-data'
           style={{
             display: 'flex',
             flexWrap: 'wrap',
             justifyContent: 'center',
             margin: '20px',
             padding: '10px',
           }}
         >
           <Typography variant='h5'>Creating a Memory</Typography>

           <TextField
             type='text'
             label='Creator'
             fullWidth
             variant='outlined'
             placeholder='Creator'
             name='creator'
             value={postGet.post.creator} // value={newUser.creator}
             onChange={handleChange}
           />
           <TextField
             type='text'
             fullWidth
             variant='outlined'
             label='Title'
             placeholder='Title'
             name='title'
             value={postGet.post.title} // value={newUser.title}
             onChange={handleChange}
           />
           <TextField
             type='text'
             placeholder='Message'
             label='Message'
             fullWidth
             variant='outlined'
             name='message'
             value={postGet.post.message} // value={newUser.message}
             onChange={handleChange}
           />
           <TextField
             type='text'
             placeholder='Tags'
             label='Tags'
             fullWidth
             variant='outlined'
             name='tags'
             value={postGet.post.tags} // value={newUser.tags}
             onChange={handleChange}
           />
           <TextField
             type='file'
             accept='.png, .jpg, .jpeg'
             fullWidth
             name='photo'
             onChange={handlePhoto}
           />

           <div className='bg'></div>

           <TextField type='submit' />
           <TextField type='button' value='Clear' />
         </form>
       </Paper>
     )
   }

   export default FormScreen
   ```

*Create post success. I create post and update post in same form*

Comment: shouldn't the dispatch action be like this: `dispatch(getPost({id}))`

Comment: Where is `post._id` defined? Nothing in the same shows how its value is set